# Add different attributes to same elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<div class="controls">
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Boardroom" name="Form[257][]">&nbsp;Boardroom</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Theatre" name="Form[257][]">&nbsp;Theatre</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="School" name="Form[257][]">&nbsp;School</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="U-shape" name="Form[257][]">&nbsp;U-shape</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Coctail" name="Form[257][]">&nbsp;Coctail</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Banquet" name="Form[257][]">&nbsp;Banquet</label>
</div>
```

And I want to add image so it become like this:

```
<div class="controls">
<label class="checkbox inline">   
<input type="checkbox" value="Boardroom" name="Form[257][]">
<img src='1.png'>&nbsp;Boardroom</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Theatre" name="Form[257][]">
<img src='2.png'>&nbsp;Theatre</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="School" name="Form[257][]">
<img src='3.png'>&nbsp;School</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="U-shape" name="Form[257][]">
<img src='4.png'>&nbsp;U-shape</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Coctail" name="Form[257][]">
<img src='5.png'>&nbsp;Coctail</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Banquet" name="Form[257][]">
<img src='6.png'>&nbsp;Banquet</label>
</div>
```

Basically, I need to add different image foreach label.Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simple

```
$('.controls label input').after(function(idx){
    return '<img src="' + (idx + 1) + '.png" />';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YE8Jg/)

Answer (score 1):

define a `data-img="/1.jpg"` for each input, and use this jquery code :

```
$('.controls .checkbox input').each(function()
{
    $(this).after( '<img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />' );
});
```

example :

```
<label class="checkbox inline"><input data-img="/images/1.jpg" type="checkbox" value="Boardroom" name="Form[257][]">&nbsp;Boardroom</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = ['1.png', '2.png', ...];
$('input:checkbox').each( function( idx, el ) {
    $( el ).after( "<img src='" + images[(idx + 1)] + " />" );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this code

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Q34W/)

```
$('.controls label input').each(function(cnt){
    $('<img src="' + (cnt + 1) + '.png" />').insertAfter(this)
})
```